# SambaCry CVE-2017-7494 returns "Exploit completed, but no session was created"

Tags: exploit, metasploit, cve

I am using this exploit on msfconsole to exploit a VM with samba and the configuration is as follows:

```
Module options (exploit/linux/samba/sambacry)
Payload options (linux/x64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp)
2   Linux x86_64 -> target
```

the rhost, rport, lhost, and lport are also set.

I run the exploit on kali linux on an aws ec2 instance. Each VM is in a different subnetwork, but I can ping one another with their respective private ip addresses.

Both VMs have no firewalls (security groups desabled allowing all inbound and outbound traffic)

The samba version I am using is 4.3.11 for ubuntu 4.4.0-1066-aws

Does anyones know the reason for me still getting "Exploit completed, but no session was created." ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82609/discussion-on-question-by-user8955046-sambacry-cve-2017-7494-returns-exploit-co).

Answer (score 1):

Target might have some sort of antivirus. Also maybe you mistyped some of data like lport,lhost.

Comment: And outbound firewall rules

Comment: @Dogeatcatworld the OP said that there are no firewalls

Comment: There is no antivirus on the machines. I think the problem might be the fact that I am using virutal machines on amazon web service environment. But I am not sure.

Comment: @schroeder true. I ran into something similar the other day, where both antivirus and firewall rules were in the way. Could be an idea to test a connection with the same RHOST/RPORT parameters between he VM's.

Comment: I did test the RHOST/RPORT between VMs with telnet on RPORT 445. The port state is on LISTEN state with smbd process PID 1005.

Comment: After I use telnet I can connect but after some time I get this message "Connection closed by foreign host."

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure if your exploit work in that version, the **4.5.9** version is vulnerable for sure.

If you are using the `reverse_tcp` payload, do a test, in your attacker machine open a port and listen (`nc -l -p <the reverse port that you are using>`), and in your target machine try to connect to your attacker machine by `nc -v <attacker> <port>`. It should be verbose enough to determine if you have connectivity or not.

If all that works, here a Docker container if you want to test this exploit against a target that is for sure vulnerable https://github.com/opsxcq/exploit-CVE-2017-7494